# Pass arraylist in intent.putExtra in Broadcast gives null in getBundleExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I'm trying to pass arraylist through a broadcast from a `Service` in an intent like this

```
ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
    for (MasterVO vo : masterVOs) {

        objects.add(vo.getMasterTables());
        objects.add(vo.getDeviceUpdateStatus());

    }
    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
    extra.putSerializable("objects", objects);
    intent.putExtra("extra", extra);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then getting it in the activity:

```
   private void updateUI(Intent intent) {

   Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extra");
    ArrayList<Object> databaseList = (ArrayList<Object>) extra.getSerializable("objects");
        fillMasterTable(databaseList);
}
```

The `onReceive()` of broadcast :

```
  private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUI(intent);
    }
};
```

I'm getting `null` in the `extra`. What am I doing wrong? I saw that there are values in the `sendBroadcast' part.

Comment: can you update code with `Broadcast Receiver`?

Comment: always try to avoid the heavy work in `BroadCastReciever`. the better way to start a service from bradcast reciever and update the UI/ activity from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `getIntent` from `activity` **not** `broadcast receiver`. Use the `intent` received in `onReceive`.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      updateUI(intent);
}

private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("extra"); //use intent NOT getIntent()
  ArrayList<Object> databaseList = (ArrayList<Object>)
  extra.getSerializable("objects");
  fillMasterTable(databaseList);
}
```